# How to pass a function as parameter without triggering parent in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I want to pass a function as a parameter in a function for a MessageBox. Here is what I tried:

```
foo: function(fnDo){
     fnDo()
}
bar: function(){
    console.log("foobar")
}
onMessageBoxshow(sMessage){
    MessageBox.warning(sMessage,
    {
      actions:["Proceed","Cancel"],
      onClose: (sAction)=>{
             if(sAction==="Proceed")
                this.foo(this.bar)
      }
    }
}
```

Expected:

User opens MessageBox

On user press proceed:

Log : "foobar"

Result:

User opens MessageBox

Log : "foobar

On user press proceed:

Log : TypeError: fnDo is not a function

Comment: Where is your `fnDo` function? If you call it without `this` it has to be a variable within the current scope. If `fnDo` is part of your controller then call `this.fnDo`

Comment: Edited the question to feature the correct function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have on close function bound to "this".
Try it with this:

```
> onClose: (sAction)=>{
>              if(sAction==="Proceed")
>                 this.foo(this.bar)
>       }.bind(this)
```